# Grant access from any host (remote or local)

Tags: mysql

I tried something like below on localhost to grant access from any host:

```
grant all on tos_db.* to 'tos'@'%' identified by 'tos';
```

However, when I tried the following command on localhost, it didn't work:

```
$ mysql -u tos -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'tos'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Then I replaced the `%` symbol with `localhost` in the grant statement. Unsurprisingly, it worked. But I am confused. Isn't the `%` symbol supposed to match any host? Or is it just for remote host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because the wildcard `%`  does not cover socket communications which thing the localhost is for.